# Issue when calling address functions from python

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

So, i want to integrate my python code with my game code(using Source Engine for the game), and i want to use the CreateInterface function from the engine.dll

I tried this code:

```
#######################################################################
# Imports
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

#######################################################################
MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
GetModuleHandle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
GetProcAddress = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress
#######################################################################
EngineFactory = WINFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_char_p, c_void_p)(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("engine.dll"), b"CreateInterface"))
dwResult = EngineFactory(b"VEngineClient013", 0)
MessageBox(0, "{0}".format(hex(dwResult)), 0, 0)
```

It didn't work, the code stops after the EngineFactory is called and i can't see the message box, i checked on ollydbg to see if the code is executing the CreateInterface function, and it is working.The app calls the function and it returns a valid pointer, but i can't receive it on the python code...

Comment: Have you tried setting the return type of `EngineFactory` so ensure that the result isn't being cast to a 32-bit int?

Comment: @ebarr `WINFUNCTYPE` does that

Comment: You'll want to do some debugging. At the very least you'll want to know that the call to `GetProcAddress` succeeds. I see no evidence that you've tested that. And we can only take your word that the function has those parameters, and that calling convention. The bottom line is that you've done something wrong, but there's not enough information here for us to diagnose it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just said i debugged it, the return from the function EngineFactory itself is OK, the problem is that that return does not go to the python, in some way between the return from the function and the python code some error occures